# Strikethrough text and formula in LaTeX

Tags: cancel, strikeout

I would like to strikethrough a combination of text and formula in LaTeX (to get the output in Image 1) and also strike out an aligned/multiline equation (like the output in Image 2). I would appreciate anyone's help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}\label{E9}
        \bullet\quad & {\color{blue} \tilde p} ~ = ~~4{b_1}{b_2}\left[ {\frac{1}{3}\left( {b_1^2 + b_2^2} \right) + \left\| {p - c} \right\|_2^2} \right] \nonumber\\
        &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad~ = 4\frac{w}{2}\frac{w}{2}\left[ {\frac{1}{3}\left( {\frac{{{w^2}}}{4} + \frac{{{w^2}}}{4}} \right) + \left\| p-c \right\|_2^2} \right] \nonumber\\
        &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad~ = {\color{blue} {w^2}\left[ {\frac{{{w^2}}}{6} + \left\| {p - c} \right\|_2^2} \right]}
    \end{align}
    
    For $d\ge 3$, based on (\ref{E9}) we can write
    \begin{align}\label{E10}
        \bullet\quad & {\color{blue}\tilde p} ~ = ~~  {2^d}\prod\limits_{i = 1}^d {{b_i}} \left[ {\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^d {b_i^2}  + \left\| p \right\|_2^2} \right] \nonumber\\
        &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad~ = {\color{blue} {w^d}\left[ {\frac{1}{3}\left( {d\frac{{{w^2}}}{4}} \right) + \left\| {p - c} \right\|_2^2} \right]}
    \end{align}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please fix your question and make it compile, we cannot run it even if it was in the format as there is no `\documentclass{}` and other stuff, please help people help you

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, Done. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the **[tikz](https://ctan.org/topic/pgf-tikz)** library to draw over the text, and the *tikzlibrary* **[tikzmark](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark)** to obtain the exact coordinates of the points from which you want to start drawing lines over the text. Additionally, importing **[tzplot](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot)** can make it easier to obtain the components of these coordinates. Otherwise, you'd need to use the verbose syntax `\path let \p1` etc.

Starting from **[@Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)**'s code:

```latex
%%%%%%%%% FIRST IMAGE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\tikzmark{AY}
\begin{equation}\label{E9}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bullet\quad\color{blue} \tilde{p} 
&= 4 b_1 b_2 
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}( b_1^2 + b^2 ) + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= 4 \frac{w}{2} \frac{w}{2}
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{w^2}{4} + \frac{w^2}{4} \right) 
   + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= \color{blue} w^2\left[ \frac{w^2}{6} + \norm{p-c}^2 \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
For $d\ge 3$, based on \eqref{E9} we can write
\begin{equation}\label{E10}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bullet\quad\color{blue} \tilde{p} 
&= 2^d \prod_{i=1}^{d} b_i 
   \biggl[ \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{d} b_i^2 + \norm{p}^2 \biggr] \\[\jot]
&= \color{blue} w^d
   \left[ \frac{1}{3} \left( d \frac{w^2}{4} \right) 
   + \norm{p-c}^2 \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\tikzmark{BY}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:AY){\anull}{\ay}
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:BY){\bnull}{\by}
\draw (0, \ay) -- (\linewidth, \by);
\draw (\linewidth, \ay) -- (0, \by);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: First Image]

```latex
%%%%%%%%% SECOND IMAGE
% [...] same code as before

\tikzmark{AY}
\begin{equation}\label{E9}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bullet\quad\color{blue} \tilde{p} 
&= \tikzmark{AX} 4 b_1 b_2 
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}( b_1^2 + b^2 ) + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= 4 \frac{w}{2} \frac{w}{2}
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{w^2}{4} + \frac{w^2}{4} \right) 
   + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= \color{blue} w^2\left[ \frac{w^2}{6} + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] 
\tikzmark{BX}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\tikzmark{BY}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:AX){\ax}{\anull}
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:AY){\anull}{\ay}
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:BX){\bx}{\bnull}
\tzgetxyval(pic cs:BY){\bnull}{\by}
\draw (\ax, \ay) -- (\bx, \by);
\draw (\bx, \ay) -- (\ax, \by);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Second Image]

If you have any further questions or need clarification on the code, don't hesitate to reach out!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Would you mind if I asked you to let me know how I can use both of them in a single document? Actually, when I use both codes, everything gets destroyed.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but it's definitely necessary for the various \tikzmark{<label>} to have different labels, otherwise TikZ will draw based on the last definition. If you intend to stack them (I'm not exactly sure in what order), you can redefine one of them as "\tikzmark{AY1}" etc. Obviously, this new name must also be used within the "tikzpicture" environment. For example, if you used "\tikzmark{AY1}", then you'll need to write "\tzgetxyval(pic cs:AY1){\ax}{\anull}"...

Answer (score 3):

(Not a direct answer to the OP's query, but a plea to de-cruft and simplify the LaTeX code.)

Your code is chock-full of unneeded pairs of curly braces and of `\left`/`\right` auto-sizing directives that do nothing useful -- but do clutter up the code. Please make de-crufting and streamlining your code a goal in and of itself. Also, unless your equations are full of both L-2 norms and L-1 norms, I think it's ok to define once that `\| ... \}` denotes the L-2 norm, letting you do away with a pedantic "2" subscript.

Decrufting and streamlining is not just an aesthetic exercise; it really helps when it becomes necessary to track down some obscure syntax error -- which can and does happen to the everyone).

E.g., I'd like suggest you rewrite the material as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}\label{E9}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bullet\quad\color{blue} \tilde{p} 
&= 4 b_1 b_2 
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}( b_1^2 + b^2 ) + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= 4 \frac{w}{2} \frac{w}{2}
   \left[ \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{w^2}{4} + \frac{w^2}{4} \right) 
   + \norm{p-c}^2 \right] \\[\jot]
&= \color{blue} w^2\left[ \frac{w^2}{6} + \norm{p-c}^2 \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
For $d\ge 3$, based on \eqref{E9} we can write
\begin{equation}\label{E10}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\bullet\quad\color{blue} \tilde{p} 
&= 2^d \prod_{i=1}^{d} b_i 
   \biggl[ \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i=1}^{d} b_i^2 + \norm{p}^2 \biggr] \\[\jot]
&= \color{blue} w^d
   \left[ \frac{1}{3} \left( d \frac{w^2}{4} \right) 
   + \norm{p-c}^2 \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```